# How do I use Materialbox

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I am trying to use Materialbox in Materialize, but the zooming effect does not seem to work. While the CSS hover works, clicking does not enlarge the image as it should.

I have tried both the jQuery method and the non-jQuery method shown on the site. I have made sure that jQuery is loaded before the script, and tried both including the script in the html in  tags as well as putting it in another file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <!--This is the where the image is-->
                <img class="materialboxed" width="300" src="assets/model.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--I used the provided code on the Materialize website--> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Looking at the console, I get three errors:

Loading failed for the  with source “file:///Users/ned/Desktop/website/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js”.

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with...

My editor throws the ReferenceError as well whenever I try to use the code snippet in a separate file.

Comment: Add `<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>` before `<script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>`. Edit: Also ensure that your path to jQuery is correct

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

instead of this:

```
<script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Actually, materialize itself uses jQuery in its code, so you must include jQuery first then `materialize.min.js`.

It works for me.